# Fate of the Skaal not working

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I cannot advance in the *[The Fate of The Skaal](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Dragonborn:The_Fate_of_the_Skaal)* questline, due to destroying the Wind Stone ages ago. Frea's father won't let me talk to him to advance the quest.

Answer (score 2):

I think both conditions (having destroyed the Wind Stone and Storn not talking) are separate issues.

- If you destroyed the Wind Stone by having obtained Bend Will's first shout before Fate of the Skaal (the only possible way to do so), the quest, according to [the Fandom page](https://elderscrolls.fandom.com/wiki/Cleansing_the_Stones#Trivia), should be skippable:

  > This quest can be completely skipped by obtaining the first word of
  >   Bend Will from Saering's Watch and shouting at the Wind Stone before
  >   meeting Frea at the Temple of Miraak. By doing so, Storn will mention
  >   the land is at peace and "The Path of Knowledge" will begin.
- Nevertheless, Storn, Frea's father, [may be taciturn](https://elderscrolls.fandom.com/wiki/The_Fate_of_the_Skaal#Bugs):

  > It is possible that once the Skaal Village has been reached that the
  >   Dragonborn will not be able to talk to Storn to begin the next quest.
  >
  > - This can be fixed by **reloading an older save**.
  > - [If on PC] **the commands** `setstage DLC2MQ03 70` **and** `setstage DLC2MQ03 200` **can be used to fix this**.

  - According to [this post](https://www.reddit.com/r/skyrim/comments/3zcb2b/the_fate_of_the_skaal_storn_wont_talk_cannot/cyl1xnv/), **the command** `setstage DLC2MQ03 10` **might also work** as well (whether or not preceded by `setstage DLC2MQ03 0`), but not optimally .
  - Another way to get passive NPCs talking, is by attacking them. Sometimes they have to fall to have their AI reset, sometimes a pacifying spell (e.g. Vampire's Seduction) is necessary. Note, also, that this doesn't always work.
  - **You might want to try destroying more All-Maker Stones**, as it will probably change some parameters in the quest progression.
  - As per [this comment](https://elderscrolls.fandom.com/wiki/Thread:344466#27), it might help to **follow Frea to Skaal Village**:

  > For me, the problem was that I did not follow Frea directly out of the
  >   Temple of Miraak, but instead opened the black book again to gain all
  >   the items there. You should follow Frea so she will tell her story on
  >   the way to Skaal Village. Then, when you arrive, she will talk to her
  >   father and after that the quest will continue so you can also talk to
  >   her father, Storn.

Let me know what worked for you, so I can improve the answer for others.